# How to implement Angular 1 Form with Component and custom validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, components

I want to implement an angular form that holds a custom component and that uses custom (asynchronous) validation.

I was not able to find any documentation on how to implement that based on angular components.

The link function used with the "normal" directive examples is not available for components. The documentation https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/docs/guide/forms does only explain how to do this with directives (requiring ngModel and using it in the link function).

How would I do this with angular components?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this and ended up here: [https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate].

I find this less invasive anyway, but it doesn't work for encapsulating validation with the element as well. In those cases I think you will still want to go with a directive as angular's guidelines themselves seem to suggest to use directives where link functions are needed.